# display build number in page footer, application deployed using azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine, build-numbers

I have deployed a website containing react as front end and node as back end using azure devops in azure vm and its working perfect. now i want to display build number & release number in page footer of the website. can anyone help with it, i'm quite new to azure devops so not able to find any helping solution.

Edit:
as suggested i have added below variables to my ci pipeline [as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPQT1.png)

and in my code i have tried to add them to footer as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdDeb.png)

but the output i'm getting is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhf2b.png)

can't get where i'm going wrong, in the code image you can see i have used one azure devops link to get build number value but i'm not sure how to get that link, i have followed this [blog](https://blog.mayanks.page/2020/11/add-git-commit-hash-and-build-number-to.html), can someone help on it

Comment: i am curious how you implemented this. as i read through, i was thinking this could be a step during release that is a powershell script to update/add something to the appsettings that would give app ability to know the build and release info.

Answer (score 1):

In the build pipeline, you can use the predefined variable **`Build.BuildNumber`** to get the build number of current build. For more details, you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).
[image]

And in the release pipeline, you can use the predefined variable **`Release.ReleaseName`** to get the release name (release number) of current release. For more details, you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#release).
[image]

In the pipelines, you can use the predefined variables to get the values you require and write them into the code of your web app to set the page footer.

Maybe, you can try to develop a script to write the build number and release name into the code of your web app, and call this script in the build pipeline and release pipeline.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to get the azure app service to read the "build.buildNumber"?